# Angular validator production

Tags: angular, validation

I have a user registration form on my site where I use a custom validator to check the registration password. It's working as expected in development (ng serve) but when I generate the production build `(ng build --prod)` the special character part stops working properly. The console is clean.

Any ideas on why this is?

Password Validator:

```
password: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8),
        this.CustomValidator.regTest(/[A-Z]/, true, 'upperCase'),
        this.CustomValidator.regTest(/[a-z]/, true, 'lowerCase'),
        this.CustomValidator.regTest(/[0-9]/, true, 'number'),
        this.CustomValidator.regTest(/[\!\"\#\¤\%\&\/\(\)\=\?\¨\^\'\*\<\>\,\;\.\:\-\_\§\½\@\£\$\€\{\}\[\]]/, true, 'special'),
        this.CustomValidator.regTest(/\s/g, false, 'blank')
      ])
```

The custom validator class and method looks as below:

```
export class CustomValidators {

    regTest(nameRe: RegExp, match: boolean, prop = 'regTest'): ValidatorFn {

        return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
            const valid = nameRe.test(control.value);
            const error = new Object();

            error[prop] = new Object();
            error[prop][prop] = control.value;

            if (match) {
                return valid ? null : error;
            } else {
                return !valid ? null : error;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Part of component that shows validation status:

```
<div class="error-container" fxFlex="100%" *ngIf="regForm.get('password').value">
      <mat-error *ngIf="regForm.get('password').getError('special')">
        Password must contain at least 1 special character
      </mat-error>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it workes as development build and not during production but changing validation of the special character to below fixed the issue. It is also a cleaner and wider approach to the special character validation requirement.

```
this.CustomValidator.regTest(/\W|_/, true, 'special')
```